# Unsupported media type for xml php curl request

Tags: php, xml, api, soap, curl

Here is my code I am using to connect to the Mind Body Online API.  If ANYONE at all has any experience with this please point me in the right direction!

The error I am getting is :The server cannot service the request because the media type is unsupported.

Code:

```
$soapUrl = "http://clients.mindbodyonline.com/api/0_5/ClassService.asmx?WSDL";
// xml post structure

$xml_post_string = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <soapenv:Header/>
  <soapenv:Body>
     <GetClasses xmlns="http://clients.mindbodyonline.com/api/0_5/GetClasses">
        <Request>
           <SourceCredentials>
              <SourceName>{user}</SourceName>
              <Password>{pass}</Password>
              <SiteIDs>
                 <int>{id}</int>
              </SiteIDs>
           </SourceCredentials>
           <XMLDetail>Basic</XMLDetail>
           <PageSize>10</PageSize>
           <CurrentPageIndex>0</CurrentPageIndex>
           <SchedulingWindow>true</SchedulingWindow>
        </Request>
     </GetClasses>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
';

$headers = array(
    "Content-type: application/xml;charset=utf-8",
    "Accept: application/xml",
    "Cache-Control: no-cache",
    "Pragma: no-cache",
    "SOAPAction: http://clients.mindbodyonline.com/api/0_5/GetClasses",
    "Content-length: ".strlen($xml_post_string),
    );

$url = $soapUrl;
$cookiePath = tempnam('/tmp', 'cookie');

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookiePath);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml_post_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

// converting
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo $response;
```

Comment: This is very tricky sir!!  Please check with firebug and attempt the process manually.  Record the successful request/response from firebug from a regular query and then we can assess what you have done wrong in your request.  A CURL request that is matched exactly with the true headers and cookies will not fail, but we cannot diagnose the problem until we know the details.  If not firebug at least try command line: "curl -I site.com/ajaxcall" and report back.  Seriously I mean you no offense as I have asked more ambiguous questions.  However, if you provide better details someone will answer.

Comment: I just encountered the same kind of error. The body of the response is what you mention but looking at the HTTP response header provides additional details like:
HTTP/1.1 415 Cannot process the message because the content type 'application/soap+xml;charset=UTF-8;action="http://www.foo.org/bar/Operation"' was not the expected type 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'.

Answer (score 10):

```
"Content-type: text/xml;charset=utf-8"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
function getAccessToken()
{
$head = array("Accept" =>"application/json",
                  "Content-type" => "multipart/form-data");
$header="";
foreach ($head as $key => $value) {
    $header .= $key . '=' . $value . '&';
}
$header = rtrim($header, '&');

$parameters="";
$params = array("grant_type"=>"client_credentials");
foreach ($params as $key => $value) {
    $parameters .= $key . '=' . $value . '&';
}
$parameters = rtrim($parameters, '&');

$url = "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$parameters);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERPWD, "ASLy4BAtBdBh1B2XfPpVdffdfdsfdutPM4l-sAnIWzrmLJ_2Y-    7VcU4qC_tH:EAH5UhDznr8jAZYeSDtODz9I2qT8WOuq2tiAJwY8HdvMN7cP3isdsdsdgy");
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    if (empty ($response) )
    {
        die (curl_error($ch));
    }

      print_r($response);
      }
     getAccessToken();
```